# Make my y-axis values more legible

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I have to create my gg-plot in R. It's not bad so far, in the sense that I successfully got it to be grouped by the correct principles and colour coded by classes. My problem is that rather than having a bunch of random y-values on the y-axis, I want an appropriate scale and bars to follow.

```
ggplot(SUMMARY.PCTDIFF, aes(principle, pctdiff)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = class),position = "dodge", stat="identity",col="black")
```

[image]

Comment: are those **principal** components? if so, please fix the spelling ...

Answer (score 2):

Your `pctdiff` variable got turned into a factor by accident.  Run

```
SUMMARY.PCTDIFF$pctdiff <- as.numeric(as.character(SUMMARY.PCTDIFF$pctdiff))
```

and recreate your plot.  Even better, look upstream in your workflow and see how you can stop this from happening (hint, fix errors in your supposedly all-numeric column/use `na.strings` argument to `read.csv`/use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and then convert to numeric explicitly ...)

Comment: Thanks Ben! Any chance you could assist with how to switch the colours for the bars as well?

Comment: what do you want to do? check `scale_fill_discrete`, `scale_fill_brewer`, `scale_fill_manual` ... or ask another question.

Comment: See the orange, green, blue, purple colours? I want to change them to different colours. I'll check those parameters in the meantime.

Comment: e.g. see the *Scales* section of the ggplot2 cheat sheet: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf